# Jacobian of a Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Usually Jacobian matrix encapsulate partial derivatives of a vector f w.r.t. another vector v.

More generally how to define/get the Jacobian matrix of a matrix F w.r.t another matrix V?

Is it just taking the elements of F and V and arranging them as vectors and getting the usual Jacobian matrix of 2 vectors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Jacobian is defined for a real function depending on a vector. You can replace the vector by a matrix by considering the matrix as a vector, or by using a four-dimensional tensor instead of a two-dimensional matrix.

Comment: thanks. Regarding the second option do you know any good online reference.