# Simple example of a Jacobian of a matrix and/or Hessian of a vector

Tags: matrices, examples-counterexamples, jacobian, hessian-matrix

I wanted to add a comment to the following:

- [Calculate the Hessian of a Vector Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2889262/calculate-the-hessian-of-a-vector-function?newreg=daee7ece16f14ab185d7faa7d2752aef)
- [Jacobian of a Matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17552/jacobian-of-a-matrix)

but I don't have enough reputation for that.

Both answers are too short for me to understand how to compute the Jacobian of a matrix and/or a Hessian of a vector.

The only thing I understood is that the final result should be a vector of matrices, but it is not clear if it's a column vector or a row vector, in which order it should be computed, and what dimension do the matrices have.

Can somebody show a complete example with a very small matrix/vector? e.g.: 
$$
\frac{\partial{\mathbf{A}(\boldsymbol{\alpha})}}{\partial \boldsymbol{\alpha}} = \begin{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial a_{11}}{\partial{\alpha_{11}}} & \dots & ? \\
\dots &\ddots & ?
\end{bmatrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial a_{??}}{\partial{\alpha_{??}}} & \dots & ? \\
\dots &\ddots & ?
\end{bmatrix}\\
\dots
\end{bmatrix} \quad\boldsymbol{\alpha} \in \mathbb{R}^3,\;\mathbf{A}(\boldsymbol{\alpha}) :\mathbb{R}^3\mapsto\mathbb{R}^{2\times3}
$$
and same for the Hessian of a small vector valued function, e.g. $\mathbf{f}(\boldsymbol{\alpha}) : \mathbb{R}^3 \mapsto \mathbb{R}^2$: